# Apache Ignite: Eviction policy mismatch

Tags: ignite

I just started out on Ignite and am able to connect a Java client node to a server node using "Hello World" example. I then added the following to the "server" example-default xml as the input for the ignite.bat in hope that I can experiment eviction policy, etc.

The server takes the block below and can start the bat script okay.

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <list>
        
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="myCache"/>

            <!-- Enabling on-heap caching for this distributed cache. -->
            <property name="onheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/> 

            <property name="evictionPolicy">
                <!-- FIFO eviction policy. -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.fifo.FifoEvictionPolicy">
                    <!-- Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000). -->
                  <property name="maxSize" value="3"/>
                </bean>
            </property>                 
        </bean>     
        
    </list>
</property>
```

On the client side, I added the code accordingly but got an exception that I can't figure out why and how to debug further.

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {

        CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheCfg.setName("myCache");
        cacheCfg.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);

        // Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000).
        cacheCfg.setEvictionPolicyFactory(() -> new FifoEvictionPolicy(3));

        // Preparing IgniteConfiguration using Java APIs
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cacheCfg);   // set the above cache configuration obj on this cfg

        // The node will be started as a client node.
        cfg.setClientMode(true);

        // Classes of custom Java logic will be transferred over the wire from this app.
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

        // Setting up an IP Finder to ensure the client can locate the servers.
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(ipFinder));

        // Starting the node
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        // Create an IgniteCache and put some values in it.
        IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");
        cache.put(1, "Welcome to XYZ");
        cache.put(2, "Testing!");
        cache.put(3, "by ABC!");
        cache.put(4, "Thanks and Goodbye");

        System.out.println(">> Created the cache and add the values.");

        // Executing custom Java compute task on server nodes.
        ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forServers()).broadcast(new RemoteTask());

        System.out.println(">> Compute task is executed, check for output on the server nodes.");

        // Disconnect from the cluster.
        ignite.close();
    }
```

Based on the error below, it looks like Ignite sees my remote node eviction policy, but it thinks my local eviction policy is null. Your advice/suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks

**class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Eviction policy mismatch [cacheName=myCache, localEvictionPolicy=null, remoteEvictionPolicy=org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.fifo.FifoEvictionPolicy, rmtNodeId=ffacf26**9-ba23-4698-b93c-68b0f4d6960e]

Answer (score 0):

A few points about this:

1. If you've defined the cache on the server, you don't need to also define it in your client. You can just skip the whole cache definition part
2. I'm not sure the eviction policy will do what you want. The policy only affects the *on-heap* cache. The on-heap cache is *in addition* to the off-heap cache. If you want to evict data from memory, you need to use the data region-level eviction policy. This works on the page rather than record level
3. An on-heap cache, caches *local* data in the Java heap. A client node doesn't have any local data. If you really want an on-heap cache (and you probably don't), you need to use a near cache

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I followed your suggestion to turn off the cache definition part on the Java client side and Ignite no longer complains.

Comment: For #2, are you referring to the 'offheap' and 'heap' as in this example? I was thinking since I specified 'onheapCacheEnabled', it looks like it makes sense for Ignite to allocate heap-only memory for the task, then free it up afterward (2GB --> 9.9GB --> 2GB) :   Topology snapshot [ver=5, locNode=3eb43ca5, servers=2, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=16, offheap=13.0GB, heap=9.9GB] 
//Some remote tasks executed here sent by the client, then the client exits.
Topology snapshot [ver=6, locNode=3eb43ca5, servers=2, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=16, offheap=13.0GB, heap=2.0GB]

Comment: That's my point. It doesn't store the records on the Java heap _instead of_ storing them off-heap. It stores it on-heap _in addition_ to storing it off-heap. The eviction policy you've defined only affects the on-heap cache.